# Problem with raw latex output in R Markdown from python function

Tags: python, r, pandas, markdown

I want to use R Markdown in combination with python and LaTeX.
I've found the module `to_latex` to convert a Pandas `DataFrame` to raw LaTeX code.
This works really fine in Python.
When I try this in Markdown I get some error messages like `Undefined control sequence. l.146 \textbackslash`. When I look into my tex-file there is some strange code, indeed. The table from the first five rows and columns of mtcars looks like the following:

```
`\textbackslash begin\{tabular\}\{llrrrr\}\n\textbackslash toprule\n{}
\& model \& mpg \& cyl \& disp \& hp
\textbackslash\textbackslash{}\n\textbackslash midrule\n0 \& Mazda RX4
\& 21.0 \& 6 \& 160.0 \& 110 \textbackslash\textbackslash{}\n1 \& Mazda
RX4 Wag \& 21.0 \& 6 \& 160.0 \& 110 \textbackslash\textbackslash{}\n2
\& Datsun 710 \& 22.8 \& 4 \& 108.0 \& 93
\textbackslash\textbackslash{}\n3 \& Hornet 4 Drive \& 21.4 \& 6 \&
258.0 \& 110 \textbackslash\textbackslash{}\n4 \& Hornet Sportabout \&
18.7 \& 8 \& 360.0 \& 175
\textbackslash\textbackslash{}\n\textbackslash bottomrule\n\textbackslash end\{tabular\}\n'
```

So there are these '\textbackslashs' that should not be there, there should be normal backslashs, LaTeX trys to escape them, I guess. Can I prevent this anyhow? My whole rmd script looks like this:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "TobiSonne"
date: "5/17/2021"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
lang: de
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \pagenumbering{gobble}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  fig.height = 4,
  fig.width = 7,
  echo = TRUE,
  fig.align  = "center",
  fig.pos = "H",
  out.extra = "", 
  warning = FALSE,
  message = FALSE)
library(reticulate)
```

```{python}
import pandas as pd
```

```{python}
Data = pd.read_csv("mtcars.csv").iloc[0:5, 0:5]
```

```{python, results = "asis"}
Data.to_latex()
```
````

Comment: Can you try `{python, results='asis'}`?

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've found a solution, see my own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have a solution:
In the YAML one has to add \usepackage{booktabs} and the last chunk must be:

````
```{python, results = "asis"}
print(Data.to_latex(escape = False))
```
````